# Как распарсить RETURNING id в PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

Привет. Использую PostgreSQL и PHP. Есть таблица с полями **id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, data JSONB NOT NULL**. Я записываю туда данные при помощи запроса из PHP:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO searches (data) VALUES ('$data') RETURNING id";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
```

И рассчитываю, что `RETURNING id` вернёт мне значение только что записанного в таблицу **id SERIAL**. Но мне возвращается строка `Resource id #4`. Что это и как это распарсить, чтобы было простое число? И откуда взялась цифра 4, если запись была произведена первый раз и её ID сейчас 1?

Comment: А вы обычные select из БД же в приложении наверняка делаете ? вот точно так же как с ними. fetch. В первом же описании на pg_query куча примеров

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO searches (data) VALUES ('$data') RETURNING id";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$row = pg_fetch_row($result);
$user_id = $row[0]; //значение ID записи
```